# Android creating geofence not working in the 3G network

Tags: android

I am working on geofence api launched in Google I/O 2013. Creating and Monitoring Geofences.and not getting any nottification in the case 3G network.but its working smoothly in the wifi connection please help me

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16769653/how-to-use-android-geofencing-api/16883613#16883613

Comment: now its working in 3G network also, i increased the radius upt0 300M

Comment: And working in gps signal? I tested the sample and not use the gps signal to reach the exact location which is supposed to use when i walk or drive in car

Comment: using gps signal its working more accurate than network condition and you can reduce the radius up to 1 m also

Comment: My question is if the sample "Creating and Monitoring Geofences" try to connect with gps signal to precise locations... because every tests the application didn't start the gps connection

Comment: some times when i trying to add Geo fences  get the error code 1000(" Add Geofences: Failure, error code 1000")

Comment: the error 1000 is "geofence_not_Available" error. check http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationStatusCodes.html probably because location is not turned on.