# Simplest way to create a static Geofence in Android Google Maps api v2

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, geofencing

I want to create a circular Block in my map that notifies me whenever I enter and exit it. And i found Google's Geofencing

My google maps and my gps tracking is all set up. And i found [this](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/implementing-map-and-geofence-features-in-android-business-apps) geofencing tutorial from intel's website and from google's website as well.

But i found those tutorial hard to understand since I'm just a beginner.

Can someone provide the easiest and simplest way to create a static Geofence on a google map?

Also is there any other technique or api or class to this function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use the Android Geofencing API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16769653/how-do-i-use-the-android-geofencing-api)

Comment: if you can't correctly setup Geofence, you could always use the Basic methods of maps api v2 (getDistance()) , setup the coordinates where you want the block to be, define a static range (10 meters, 15 meters) variable , and check distance from user's grps center to block's gprs center + range on a asynctask. as it's from the center, you'll be drawing a circle around those coordinates. but using Geofecing is the way to go as it provides more accuracy and more methods.